# Replacing ID values of polygons in a geodataframe to values of polygons from another geodataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, geopandas, fiona

I have polygons inside another bigger single polygon and I want to be able to replace the ID values (for example) of the former polygon to that of the latter.

Suppose I have a geodataframe with 3 polygons and the IDs of them are `[8, 20, 55]`. Now, these polygons are actually inside another bigger polygon (second geodataframe) with an ID of `[2]`. I want to know how it is possible to convert the values of `[8,20,55]` from the first geodataframe to `[2,2,2]` according to the bigger polygon from the second geodataframe. Conceptually the image looks like this:

[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html):

```
gdf1['ID'] = gdf1.sjoin(gdf2, how='left', predicate='within')['ID_right']
```

Comment: I did try with sjoin but I always had the issue of NaN values popping up for some reason. No idea why.

Comment: It means some polygons from df1 are (partially) outside of polygons of df2. Try to replace 'within' by 'intersects'.